# Does RestKit perform requests on different threads?

Tags: ios, multithreading, restkit

As the title states, does [RestKit](http://restkit.org/) perform my requests on a new thread automatically? Or is it something I have to do myself? I've taken a look at all their feature descriptions but not seen anything specific about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a quick look at the Restkit sources for you and I found that the **RKHTTPRequestOperation** is a subclass of **AFHTTPRequestOperation**, which in turn is a subclass of **AFURLConnectionOperation**. This is what I found in the last one:

```
+ (NSThread *)networkRequestThread {
    static NSThread *_networkRequestThread = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t oncePredicate;

    dispatch_once(&oncePredicate, ^{
        _networkRequestThread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(networkRequestThreadEntryPoint:) object:nil];
        [_networkRequestThread start];
    });

    return _networkRequestThread;
}
```

So, to answer your question: yes. Restkit creates a new thread for the requests. Note that it creates exactly one thread for the requests, it does not spawn a thread for each request.